# How to avoid losing type hinting of decorated function

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, decorator, python-3.8, type-hinting

I noticed that when wrapping a function or method that have some type hinting then the wrapped method loses the type hinting informations when I am coding using Visual studio code.

For example with this code:

```
from typing import Callable
import functools

def decorate(function: Callable):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(object: "A", *args, **kwargs):
        return function(object, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class A:
    @decorate
    def g(self, count: int) -> str:
        return f"hello {count}"

a = A()

print(a.g(2))
```

When I am hovering within visual studio code over the name g then I lose the type hinting informations.
Would you know a way to prevent this?

Sincerely

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best you can do with Python 3.8 (and 3.9) is the following:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")


def decorate(function: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[..., T]:
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(obj: A, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
        return function(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class A:
    @decorate
    def g(self, count: int) -> str:
        return f"hello {count}"
```

This will preserve the return type information, but no details about the parameter types. The `@wraps` decorator should at least keep the signature intact. If the decorator is supposed to be universal for methods of `A`, this is as good as it gets IMO.

If you want it to be more specific, you can always restrict the function type to `Callable[[A, B, C], T]`, but then the decorator will not be as universal anymore.

---

If you upgrade to Python [3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-612-parameter-specification-variables), you will have access to [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec). Then you can do the following:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar


P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")


def decorate(function: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class A:
    @decorate
    def g(self, count: int) -> str:
        return f"hello {count}"
```

This actually preserves (as the name implies) all the parameter specifications.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does actually! Thank you very much for this detailed explanation.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, you can use ParamSpecs in Python 3.9 . You just need to import it from typing_extensions, instead of typing.